# Prove $(x,y)\rightarrow f(x,y)=\dfrac {\cos(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1+y)}\in L^{1}(]0,+\infty×]-1,1[)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals

today I have a question about  prove this function
$$(x,y)\rightarrow f(x,y)=\dfrac {\cos(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1+y)}$$
Such that  $(x,y)\in ]0,+\infty ×]-1,1[$ are integrable.

**My attempts **

I was  use this result

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos xy}{x^2 + 1}  dx = \frac{\pi e^{-y}}{2}$$
But Where I complet i get this divergante integral
$$\int\limits_{-1}{1}\dfrac{\pi e^{-y}}{2(1+y)}dy$$
Also when I start by integrate respect to $y$ also I have divergante integral.

So how can I prove

$$f\in L^{1}(]0,+\infty×]-1,1[)$$

Comment: Just to confirm, the integral is 
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xy)}{\left(y + 1\right)\left(x^2 + 1\right)}\:dx\:dy
$$

Comment: I think there is a problem when $y$ is near $-1$. The statement is false.

Comment: Yes sir this function is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for $0<y<1$ the functions $f(y)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{|\cos(xy)|}{1+x^2}dx\geq g(y)$ where
$g(y)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{k\pi}{y}}^{\frac{k\pi}{y}+\frac{\pi}{4y}}\frac{|\cos(xy)|dx}{1+x^2}\geq h(y)$ and where
$$h(y)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{k\pi}{y}}^{\frac{k\pi}{y}+\frac{\pi}{4y}}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{y}{y^2+\pi^2k^2+\frac{\pi^2yk}{4}}>Ky>0$$  where $K$ is a positive constant since $y<1.$ Then $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{1+y}f(|y|)dy\geq \int_{-1}^1\frac{K|y|}{1+y}dy=+\infty.$$

Edit. If $f$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$ we say that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converge to $L\in R$ if $$\lim_{T\to \infty} \int_0^{T} f(x)dx=L.$$ We say that $f$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ if $\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)|dx<\infty$ (which implies of course that both $\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)|dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ are convergent. Example: $L$ exists for $f(x)=\sin x/x$ but $f$ is not integrable. The set $L^1([0,\infty))$ is the space of all integrable functions.

Similar definitions occur for $f$ defined  on $(-1,1]$ (say) with $L=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-1+\epsilon}^1f(x)dx.$ Your question was using the symbol $L^1$. The proof above shows that the function cannot belong to $L^1.$ Wolfram is wrong if it says so. What it may be meant by Wolfram is to say that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-1+\epsilon}^1\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos xy} {(1+y)(1+x^2)}dx\right)dy$$ exists and is finite.

Actually, I have doubts since $$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos xy} {(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|y|}!$$

Comment: Thank but by wolframalpha.com I get convergant integral  why?